# save image from remote server to local using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to copy image from any remote server to my local server using javascript / jQuery. Please anyone help me out.

Same like copy() function in php.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Local server? JavaScript/Jquery runs in the client and they cannot access any files directly from a remote server. The client are mostly your browsers.

If you know the file path for your remote server and if your have access to it, you can just open the file using window.open("http://remoteserver/filename.jpg")

This would download the file to the client or your computer.